# If $X_n \overset{\mathbf{P}}{\to} X$ and $X_n$ is monotonic then $X_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to}$ $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ and $X_n \le X_{n+1}$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you are a new user, I would like to encourage you to explain how you found the problem and what you did to find a solution intead of posting the question alone (btw the dislike is not mine)

Coming to the question, since a real random variable is just a measurable function from a space $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$ to $\mathbb R$, you can say that, being the sequence $X_n(\omega)$ decreasing pointwise for every $\omega \in \Omega$, then

$$\exists \lim_n\ X_n(\omega)=X_0(\omega) \qquad X_n \overset{a.s.}\to X_0$$

Possibly, having $X(\omega)=-\infty$ for some $\omega$. Then, since the convergence a.s. is stronger than the convergence in probability,

$$X_n \overset{\mathbb P}\to X_0$$

but since the limit in probability is unique, $X=X_0$ almost surely. This imples

$$X_n \overset{a.s.}\to X$$